# PHP: Better algorithm to strict typed identify duplicates in an array

Tags: php, arrays, strong-typing, unify

While looking for a solution to identify duplicates in an array I stumpled upon many kinds of solutions counting on  `array_count_values` or `array_unique`. But all of these solutions doesn't care about objects in the array.

`array_count_values` throws an `E_WARNING` for every value which isn't a `string` or an `integer`.

`array_unique` does take care about elements with various types if the option `SORT_REGULAR` has been set. But take a look at the use case as follows.

```
class Foo
{
    private $value;

    public function __construct( $value )
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
}

$f1 = new Foo( 42 );
$f2 = $f1;
$f3 = new Foo( 42 );
$f4 = new Foo( '42' );
$f5 = new Foo( 'Bar' );
$a  = [ $f1, $f2, $f3, $f4, $f5 ];
```

After a unification with `array_unqiue` I expected to get an array with 4 elements `[ $f1, $f3, $f4, $f5 ]`. But it states out, that `array_unqiue` is working loose-typed and I got `[ $f1, $f5 ]` which isn't the result I need.

In my case I wrote a collection working like a set. I can pass some initial elements. These elements should be validated. If one element is a duplicate an exception have to be thrown. In order of the loose-typed `array_unqiue` I came up with this solution (which can be adapted very easy to unify an array).

```
$boundN = count( $elements );
$boundM = $boundN - 1;
for ( $m = 0; $m < $boundM; $m++ )
{
    for ( $n = $m + 1; $n < $boundN; $n++ )
    {
        if ( $elements[ $m ] === $elements[ $n ] )
        {
            throw new DuplicateElementException( 'The initial values contain duplicates.' );
        }
    }
}
```

At least I minified the iterations in the inner loop. One can assume, that all passed elements in the outer loop are validated and don't have to be validated again.

My question is: Is there a shorter algorithm equal to algorithms like `Quick Search` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, it's the specific instance of each object which is unique. The [spl_object_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-id.php) method can get a unique identifier for each object, and you can use those as keys in an associative array to collapse for duplicates. There are a few shorthand ways to write it, but a self-contained example might be:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    private $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this -> data = $data;
    }
}

$f1 = new Foo( 42 );
$f2 = $f1;
$f3 = new Foo( 42 );
$f4 = new Foo( '42' );
$f5 = new Foo( 'Bar' );
$a  = [ $f1, $f2, $f3, $f4, $f5 ];
$b = obj_unique($a);

print_r($b);

function obj_unique(array $not_unique) {
    $tmp = [];
    foreach($not_unique as $value) {
      $tmp[spl_object_id($value)] = $value;
    }
    return array_values($tmp);
}
```

This creates the following output, which is missing the duplicate values.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Foo Object
        (
            [data:Foo:private] => 42
        )

    [1] => Foo Object
        (
            [data:Foo:private] => 42
        )

    [2] => Foo Object
        (
            [data:Foo:private] => 42
        )

    [3] => Foo Object
        (
            [data:Foo:private] => Bar
        )

)
```

This idea could be trivially modified to throw an exception if the array already contains the key.

```
if(contains_duplicates($a)) {
    throw new Exception("Duplicates are bad etc etc ...");
}

function contains_duplicates(array $test) {
    $tmp = [];
    foreach($test as $value) {
      $key = spl_object_id($value);
      if(array_key_exists($key, $tmp)) {
          // duplicates
          return true;
      }
      $tmp[$key] = $value;
    }
    // no duplicates
    return false;
}
```

The `===` operator on an Object [has the same behaviour](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) as this. It is an instance-wise comparison, not a comparison of the contents of the object, which is something you should be aware of.

Comment: This is something I call dope. I didn't realize `spl_object_id()` - a fact that made it impossible to hashmap objects. BUT: I didn't mention that there can be scalar types in the array. But it doesn't matter while I can modify your solution as well. I need two temporary arrays, one for scalar values, one for object IDs. And yes, I'm aware of using strict comparison while I wanted an instance-wise comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the XY problem.

Since your code is looking for duplicate instances (===) rather than just objects containing the same data, these objects must be instantiated at run time. Since you are using a numerically indexed array it suggests you are not concerned with preserving information in the array index. Hence the most appropriate solution would be to apply a method of array indexing that ensures uniqueness as you add entries to the array:

```
 $f1 = new Foo( 42 );
 $f2 = $f1;
 $f3 = new Foo( 42 );
 $f4 = new Foo( '42' );
 $f5 = new Foo( 'Bar' );
 $a  = [ 
   spl_object_hash($f1)=>$f1, 
   spl_object_hash($f2)=>$f2, 
   spl_object_hash($f3)=>$f3, 
   spl_object_hash($f4)=>$f4, 
   spl_object_hash($f5)=>$f5 
   ];
```

Comment: Please take a look at the comment below @mike42's solution. The array can consist of several elements of several types. In my real world problem I'm taking care of the indices, while I implemented the iterator interface to iterate over my collection. This forces me to numeric index my array in the order of [0..n].

Comment: ...and as you said in your comment, that the array contains different things other than objects is far from insurmountable. You seem to be saying that you need a numeric index on your array - but this was not stated in the question and is not required to implement an iterator.

Comment: @symbecan "and is not required to implement an iterator" Why not? I have to store the position somewhere, which directly references to the array indices. If `next()` is called I have to count up my position until the maximum index, which is checked with `valid()` and so on. If you have a better solution please show me. May would make my code a lot of easier.

Comment: You could use the example in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: @symbecan There was a specific reason I decided once to store the position in an internal field instead of using `key()`. I have to digg into it again. If I found out I'll let you know.